# The usage of template-template structure declaration

Tags: c++, recursion, struct, range, c++20

I am trying to deduce the base type of `std::array` containers. The experimental implementation is like below.

```
//  A recursive_array_unwrap_type Struct Implementation in C++

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <concepts>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

//  recursive_array_unwrap_type struct implementation
template<std::size_t, typename>
struct recursive_array_unwrap_type { };

template<template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
              typename T,
              std::size_t N>
struct recursive_array_unwrap_type<1, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
              typename T,
              std::size_t N>
requires (  std::ranges::input_range<Container<T, N>> &&
            requires { typename recursive_array_unwrap_type<
                                    unwrap_level - 1,
                                    std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>>::type; })                //  The rest arguments are ranges
struct recursive_array_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, Container<T, N>>
{
    using type = typename recursive_array_unwrap_type<
        unwrap_level - 1,
        std::ranges::range_value_t<Container<T, N>>
        >::type;
};

template<std::size_t unwrap_level, template<class, std::size_t> class Container,
              typename T,
              std::size_t N>
using recursive_array_unwrap_type_t = typename recursive_array_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, Container<T, N>>::type;

int main()
{
    auto test_array = std::array<double, 5>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    recursive_array_unwrap_type_t<1, decltype(test_array)> a;   //  <- error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template
    std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(test_array)> b;         //  the type of a and the type of b should be the same
    std::cout << typeid(test_array).name();
    return 0;
}
```

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/7GaK1jndd)

However, the error `error: template argument for template template parameter must be a class template or type alias template` occurred. I suspect the issue is related to recursive_array_unwrap_type struct declaration, especally in line 17 `template<std::size_t, typename>`. I've tried other things like `template<std::size_t, template<class, std::size_t> class, typename, std::size_t>` or just `template<std::size_t, template<class, std::size_t> class>`, but the results come more worse I think. How can I resolve this issue? Please give me some hint or keywords.

Comment: `recursive_array_unwrap_type_t` expects four template arguments, of which the second is a class template. You are passing two, and the second is a type, not a template. Make it `template<std::size_t unwrap_level, typename Container> using recursive_array_unwrap_type_t = typename recursive_array_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, Container>::type;`. That at least [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/8hrecdEEe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alias should be:

```
template<std::size_t unwrap_level, class Container>
using recursive_array_unwrap_type_t = typename recursive_array_unwrap_type<unwrap_level, Container>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8aGfeKaEW)